# Can't get Select Command to work in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I want to list the Names of all web applications in IIS using the `Get-WebApplication` command.

```
Get-WebApplication -site "Default Web Site"
```

This works, and returns these something like this

```
Name             Application pool   Protocols    Physical Path
----             ----------------   ---------    -------------
test.com         test.comAppPo      http         E:\Sites\test.com
```

I just want to see the application name so I used -

```
Get-WebApplication -site "Default Web Site" | Select Name
```

No results are returned. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What the result returned from the Get-WebApplication -Site "Default Web Site"?

Comment: It wasn't clear in my original question. Should make sense now.

Comment: Okay so you want the Application pool's name test.comAppPo is that correct? Not Name -> test.com?

Comment: I want the Application Name. So for example "test.com" and not the application pool name.

Comment: Try my answer and see how you go, let me know.

Comment: Can this help? https://melcher.it/2013/03/powershell-list-all-iis-webapplications-net-version-state-identity/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
Get-WebApplication -Site "Default Web Site" | Select applicationPool
```

By the way you can use PowerShell to find the members of the first commands by piping it to | Get-Member like so.

```
Get-WebApplication | Get-Member
```

This gives you a list of properties and methods on that first command.

(cmdlets) | get-member

NOTE: that is how you can work out what columns you're meant to select and also how I got the **'applicationPool'** value in the commands above.

Comment: @danstan you're most welcome, everything you need in PowerShell can be  learnt from the get-help cmdlet or help for short :). Good luck!

Comment: @TheLazyChap Not only get-help, there are also get-command and get-member to learn when you get deeper. The latter allows you to learn not only about cmdlets but also about internal .NET object structure, so that you can do "undocumented" stuff with them.